# When does Luke learn about his father?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker

When, exactly, does Luke learn about his father?  By that, I don't mean the reveal in ESB about Vader being his father.  I mean, when does he learn that his father was a Jedi Knight?

I was watching Ep. IV again with my son last night, and it occurred to me that Luke doesn't so much as flinch when Obi Wan mentions that he was a Jedi Knight alongside his father.  So, it stands to reason that he already knew this.  But how?  Who told him?  When?  And what other information did he have about him?  His name?

Comment: He didn't flinch? He specifically says that his father was navigator on a spice freighter, and had not participated in the clone wars.

Comment: I think the lack of flinching is more a comment on Mark Hamill's (lack of) acting skills than on the script. (Also, this is one of several scenes which is not really consistent with the prequels.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He didn't already know.

From *A New Hope*'s transcript:

```
                    INT. KENOBI'S DWELLING

           The small, spartan hovel is cluttered with desert junk but 
           still manages to radiate an air of time-worn comfort and 
           security. Luke is in one corner repairing Threepio's arm, as 
           old Ben sits thinking.

                                 LUKE
                     No, my father didn't fight in the 
                     wars. He was a navigator on a spice 
                     freighter.

                                 BEN
                     That's what your uncle told you. He 
                     didn't hold with your father's ideals. 
                     Thought he should have stayed here 
                     and not gotten involved.

                                 LUKE
                     You fought in the Clone Wars?

                                 BEN
                     Yes, I was once a Jedi Knight the 
                     same as your father.

                                 LUKE
                     I wish I'd known him.
```

Clearly, he didn't know his father was a Jedi before Obi-Wan told him.

Comment: Ahhh...  I must have missed the initial exchange.  My son was probably talking during the movie... again.  :)  Thanks!